# ASIO async_write with empty buffer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

What happens when an ASIO `async_write` is invoked with zero bytes in the outgoing buffer?

Example:

```
// Assume data is a member with appropriate lifetime for duration of handler, but data.size() == 0

boost::asio::async_write(stream_,
    boost::asio::buffer(data.data(), data.size()),
    beast::bind_front_handler(&MyClass::on_write, this->shared_from_this()));
```

Does the `on_write()` handler get invoked immediately, never get called, or is it undefined what happens? Nothing in the docs seems to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier releases, the handler would be invoked once the socket became writable.  This is similar to the [null_buffers](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html) case.  Those classes are deprecated, but I believe the behavior is still present.